# How to take string from edittext and search it against Sqlite database and display result on list view in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

I want to be able to enter a name in edit text in my activity_search_friend and on click search the database. If that name is in the database i want to be able to display it on list view in my list friend activity.

i have added a getName method in dbhelper but i dont hink that it is correct
here is my code

DBHelper

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.provider.Contacts.SettingsColumns.KEY;


 public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 private static String DB_NAME = "FriendDB";
 private static final int DB_VER = 1;
 public  static  final String DB_TABLE =  "Friend";
 public static final String  DB_COLUMN = "FriendFName";
 public static final String  DB_COLUMN1 = "Last";
 public static final String  DB_COLUMN2 = "Email";
 public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VER);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String str = "CREATE TABLE Friend (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
 AUTOINCREMENT, FriendFName TEXT NOT NULL, Last TEXT NOT NULL, Email TEXT 
 NOT NULL);";
    db.execSQL(str);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String str = String.format("DELETE TABLE IF EXISTS %s",DB_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(str);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void insertNewFriend(String friend,String last,String email){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DB_COLUMN,friend);
    //values.put(DB_COLUMN1,last);
    //values.put(DB_COLUMN2,email);
    db.insert(DB_TABLE,null,values);
    db.close();
}

public void deleteFriend(String friend){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(DB_TABLE,"FriendFName = ?", new String[] {friend});
    db.close();
}


public Cursor getName(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE " +
            DB_COLUMN + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    return res;
}


public ArrayList<String> getFriendList(){
    ArrayList<String> friendList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE,new String[]
    {DB_COLUMN},null,null,null,null,null);
    int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        friendList.add(cursor.getString(index));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return friendList;
}
```

}

SearchFriend.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SearchFriend extends AppCompatActivity {

DbHelper dbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_friend);
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
}
```

}

Activity_search_friend.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.lukey.friends.SearchFriend">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="285dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/search_name"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="211dp"
    android:text="@string/button_submit_search"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: no error yet im new to android and cant figure out how to code something like that

Comment: Did you read the documentation about sqlite, views, activities?

Comment: try this tutorial. You should learn the basic first
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/database/sqlite/sqlitedatabase/android-sqlite-example/

Answer (score 0):

> i have added a getName method in dbhelper but i dont hink that it is
>   correct here is my code

```
public Cursor getName(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE " +
            DB_COLUMN + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    return res;
}
```

This will return a Cursor that contains all columns for all rows where the column named `FriendFName` equals the provided integer converted to a string.

It is unlikely to return anything unless FreindFname is numeric e.g. if Fname is Fred,Bert etc it will never locate them.

If the method were :-

```
public Cursor getName(String nametofind) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE " +
            DB_COLUMN + "=?", new String[]{nametofind});
    return res;
}
```

Then it would find non-numeric FriendFName, such as Fred.

However, if you have obtained the id and are using that to search, then your method would be :-

```
public Cursor getName(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE " +
            "_id" + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    return res;
}
```

All of the above return a Cursor, to get the FriendFname value you would have to **move** within the Cursor to the pertinent row (or rows). e.g. `yourcursor.moveToFirst();`, you would then have to get the relevant data, e.g. to get the FreindFname, you could use `yourcursor.getString(yourcursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN));`

e.g. you could have :-

```
String friendsFname = "";
if (yourcursor.movetoFirst()) {
    friendsFname = yourcusror.getString(yourcursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN));
}
```

However, if the only intention of the getName method is to retrieve the name then it might as well return the name rather than a cursor. The following would do this (assuming you are getting the id of the clicked item as per your original coding):-

```
public String getName(int id) {
    String rv = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE " +
            "_id" + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    if(res.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN));
    }
    res.close();
    return rv;
}
```

Noting that an empty string will be returned if not found, and also that the code hasn't been tested so there might be the odd typo.